# SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model Add Sharepoint user/group to every document library folder programatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, object, model, client

I have the code below that I cobbled together via various pieces found via google search etc.

The code works like a champ to provide a treeview of the various libraries and folders within them.

Recently we had an important user accidentally removed from the system and when that happened, it was also removed from every library & folder it was it (which was every single one).. (we have broken the permissions for every folder and do not inherit permissions at library or folder levels)

I figured this app code goes recursively through all the libraries and folders on the site... I could just add a bit of code to add the user to each folder with it.

My problem is that every example/suggestion I've found so far has Folder.item.blahblahblah
but I have no method called "item" in my folder object(s)

Any hints or outright step-by-step fixes for my code below to do what I need?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Net;




namespace red
{
    public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "It Begins...\r\n";

            string SitenameDev = @"https://portal/sites/devv/team";
            string SitenameProd = @"https://portal/sites/";

            ClientContext clientcontext = new ClientContext(SitenameProd);
            clientcontext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sitecollectionadminacct", "pswd", "Domain");


                //Load Libraries from SharePoint
                clientcontext.Load(clientcontext.Web.Lists);
                clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (List list in clientcontext.Web.Lists)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (list.BaseType.ToString() == "DocumentLibrary" && !list.IsApplicationList && list.Title != "Form Templates" && list.Title != "Customized Reports" && list.Title != "Site Collection Documents" && list.Title != "Site Collection Images" && list.Title != "Images")
                        {
                            clientcontext.Load(list);
                            clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                            clientcontext.Load(list.RootFolder);
                            clientcontext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
                            clientcontext.Load(list.RoleAssignments);
                            clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                            TreeViewLibraries.ShowLines = true;
                            TreeNode LibraryNode = new TreeNode(list.Title);
                            //MessageBox.Show(LibraryNode.Name);


                            TreeViewLibraries.Nodes.Add(LibraryNode);

                            if (!list.Title.StartsWith("Nothing here"))
                            {  
                                foreach (Folder SubFolder in list.RootFolder.Folders)
                                {
                                    if (SubFolder.Name != "Forms")
                                    {
                                        TreeNode MainNode = new TreeNode(SubFolder.Name);
                                        LibraryNode.Nodes.Add(MainNode);
                                        FillTreeViewNodes(SubFolder, MainNode, clientcontext);
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    catch  (Exception eee)
                    {
                    }
                }
        }

        //Recursive Function
        public void FillTreeViewNodes(Folder SubFolder, TreeNode MainNode, ClientContext clientcontext)
        {
            clientcontext.Load(SubFolder.Folders);
            clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (Folder Fol in SubFolder.Folders)
                {   
                    TreeNode SubNode = new TreeNode(Fol.Name);
                    MainNode.Nodes.Add(SubNode);
                    FillTreeViewNodes(Fol, SubNode, clientcontext);

                    //ListItem Fole = new ListItem();
                }

        }


        private void TreeViewLibraries_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Node: " + e.Node.Text);
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Parent: " + e.Node.Parent.Text);
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Parent: " + "None!");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestions: stop ignoring exceptions, and don't even _try_ to catch `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I appreciate that exceptions shouldn't be ignored.. This isn't fleshed out code yet.. pretty much proof of concept that I saved to flesh out if I needed something like it in the future. Turned out I could, but still haven't figured out why I can't access roleAssignment when Im looping through the folders.    Thanks for the link to "Should..." btw..., I'll git it a read.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientContext = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("URL");

var user = (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Principal)clientContext.Web.EnsureUser("domain\user");

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery caml = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery();

caml.ViewXml = //CAML QUERY HERE...

caml.FolderServerRelativeUrl = //relative path here...

items = objList.GetItems(caml);

clientContext.Load(items);

clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password,domain);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

item = items[0];

item.BreakRoleInheritance(true, true);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

// You may choose the asscess right here
var reader = clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType.Reader);

var collRdb = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext) { reader };

item.RoleAssignments.Add(user, collRdb);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();